# Как найти Name в ResourceKey?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, 3d

Здравствуйте. Есть такой код. Как достучаться до `Name ScaleTransform` в `Transform3DGroup` из кода?

```
<Viewport3D x:Name="Viewport3D_1" Visibility="Visible" Width="769" Height="572">
    <Viewport3D.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <Transform3DGroup x:Key="Transform_Model_Cube">
                <ScaleTransform3D x:Name="fcb" CenterX="0" CenterY="0" CenterZ="0" ScaleX="0"
                ScaleY="1" ScaleZ="1" />
            </Transform3DGroup>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Viewport3D.Resources>
</Viewport3D>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Согласно документации [директивы x:Name](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms752290.aspx):

> Как было сказано ранее, не следует применять `x:Name` (или `Name`) в ситуациях, в которых также используется `x:Key`. WPF `ResourceDictionary` обладает особым поведением при определении себя в области видимости имен XAML, однако возвращает значение `Not Implemented` или `NULL` для ключевых API `INameScope`, как способ принудительно реализовать это поведение. Если средство синтаксического анализа XAML WPF встречает `Name` или `x:Name` в определенном XAML `ResourceDictionary`, имя не добавляется ни в одну из областей видимости имен XAML. При попытке найти это имя из любой области видимости имен XAML методы `FindName` не возвратят допустимые результаты.

Проще говоря, не следует использовать `x:Name` внутри `ResourceDictionary`.

Comment: А как же тогда быть, если мне нужно получить доступ к свойствам   ScaleTransform3D находящегося внутри Transform3DGroup ResourceDictionary?